# Custom Post-type not returning the right child_of

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

**Situation**

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to give Custom Post Types a checkbox. If this box is checked, it should be returned by this Query. The Query works this far.

**The issue**

The pages I want it to display are all childs of a page. And this Query returns all pages with the checkbox, instead of just the childs of the current page with the checkbox.

**My code**

*top of page*

```
<?php $tid = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

*Further along the page*

```
<?php
  $i == 0;
  global $post;
  $myposts = new WP_Query(array(
     'post_type' => 'keuringen',
     'child_of' => $tid,
     'meta_query' => array(
         array(
         'key' => 'first_to_load',
         'value' => '1',
         'compare' => '=='
         )
     )
  ));
?>
```

**The question**
What can I do to make it return only the children? Or should this already return only the children and is this a bug in one of the plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP_Query doesn't have `child_of` argument.

All you can do is to add `post_parent` argument, but it will work a little bit different - it selects only posts with `parent` set to given page. (It will return only direct children, and not grandchildren of given page/post).

Comment: I think this might be it. The wordpress documentation isn't as clear as it could be on this subject. If this works, I'll resolve it in 9 minutes.